# Event for ckeditor content changed

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

If possible, how can we to the event of ckeditor's content being changed? For instance, there's some text already inserted into the ckeditor's content aka textarea when the page is opened. Afterwards I type something more or delete some of that text. Is there some event that's fired I can get to to change a variable when the text is changed?

I have this for regular textareas:

```
$("input,textarea").on("input", function () {
    booleanvar= true;
});
```

Saw a possible solution somewhere that had this:

```
$('.ckeditor').ckeditorGet().on('key', function (e) {
    //some code
});
```

Tried it, but didn't work. And yes I know my ckeditor's textarea has "ckeditor" as its class so that's not the reason for it not to work.

So something like those examples I can use to get to some sort of textchanged event of ckeditor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to listen to basic events in CKEditor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721916/how-to-listen-to-basic-events-in-ckeditor)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, there is the very handy `change` even that you can listen to. Documentation here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change

Use it for example like so (change editor1 to your editor instance):

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('change', function() { 
    console.log("TEST");
});
```

Comment: That probably works, but the method only gets called when the page loads (at which moment the ckeditor isn't instantiated yet) and then doesn't get called anymore, is that supposed to happen?
Note that I'm replacing the textarea for ckeditor by simply setting the textarea's class="ckeditor"

Comment: Ok that's solved, just needed to add `CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );` right before the `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on....` so that it'd be already instantiated. Works fine afterwards

Comment: Justa a remark: **change** event is fired from **undo** plugin, so you need to have undo plugin in order to use change event.

Comment: Tried a bunch of implementations but only this one worked (version 4.5)

Comment: @MarekLewandowski thanks for this hint..didn't even know I forgot the undo plugin..this note shoul be added to docs

Comment: How can I find the ckeditor instance? like you said the replace the editor1 with your ckeditor instance?

Comment: @Ahmad On the page where you have the editor, check the contents of the  `CKEDITOR.instances` variable, that will tell you :). The Developer tools toolbar (F12 in most browsers) is very, very useful - practically mandatory for modern javascript development and you can use the console there to check.

Answer (score 22):

Hope this might help someone else who comes across this post like me.. If you are using CKEditor5, could try this:

```
ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
.then(editor => {
    editor.model.document.on('change:data', (evt, data) => {
        console.log(editor.getData());
    });
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error('Editor initialization error.', error);
});
```

Comment: Helps me!! Thanks

Comment: Working perfectly! Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

It helps me a lot, for onchange of **CKEDITOR**.

```
<textarea id="ckeditor_textarea " name="ckeditor_textarea ">Add Yore Data</textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckeditor_textarea ', {});
// editor is object of your CKEDITOR
editor.on('change',function(){
    console.log("test");
});
</script>
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Or even shorter: CKEDITOR.replace('TextArea1', {}).on('change', function(){...});

Answer (score 5):

If you have a lot of ckeditor (version 4) in one page you could use this code:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function(event) {
 var editor = event.editor,
 element = editor.element;
 editor.on('change', function() {
 console.log(element.getId());
 });
 });
```

Comment: Great, that's what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Simple jQuery event binding for CKEditor4

```
$.fn.onDataChange = function (func) {
    var func = func || function () { };
    CKEDITOR.instances[$(this).attr('id')].on('change', function () {
        func();
    });
}
```