# CKEDITOR on change fires event on every character inluding space change. How to make it like normal js onchange event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm using the `CKEDITOR 4`  `onchange` event like mentioned here [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087039/event-for-ckeditor-content-changed/28087565)
. I have 10 text areas which act as a `CKeditor`. I'm planning to use on change event to pass the data to ajax and save it to database for faster saving but the problem is `CKeditor` `onchange` fires every character's change. If that happened,then there will be lot of requests to `DB`. how to make it like normal `onchange` means if particular `textarea's` data completely edited then the `ajax` request will make request to `DB`. help me to achieve this. code that has been used for `onchange`

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('change', function() { 
    console.log("TEST");
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to trigger on click of document. Check weather text in editor changed or not. If changed. Make a ajax Request

Comment: Hi Prashanth, you mean onclick for the textarea?

Comment: Please use {blur} event. I was wrongly searching for {on change} event