# How can I find the available event list provided by CKeditor 4?

Tags: javascript, events, ckeditor4.x

As title.

I tried to find the available event list in official doc but can't. Though I can find all available event from its source code by search `.fire("/s+")`. But it is not efficient because I still need to read the context to know where the event triggered.

Anyone know where I can find the event list?
or How I can know the event name fired by specific object, e.g. widget, dialog definition, etc.. ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked this [thread](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Available-events-list)?

Comment: Seems the link provided in the last post (of the above given thread) is broken

Comment: @n0m4d I did, but not helpful.

Comment: @DavidR Yes, it is dead link.

Comment: Someone has updated the list in [link]http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Event-List) in another thread. Unfortunately the diffpaste.com is down.

Comment: Great work @DavidR thanks for posting the updated link =)

Comment: @DavidR How about CKeditor 4? I feel sorry I forget to specify this in question. I update it now.

Comment: @JimmyKo Also checkout this article - https://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/2009/09/ckeditor-events.html . Looks promising!

Comment: @JimmyKo I found another thread that seems promissing. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721916/how-to-listen-to-basic-events-in-ckeditor) one and tell us if it suit your needs

Comment: @n0m4d Thanks for the information, it is not exactly what I want. I did find the similar thing in CK4, but it looks like a event callback list rather then the event name list. Or are they same?

Comment: @JimmyKo For CKEditor4, Go to this link, http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor and hover on the "Events" icon, you'll get all the events.

Comment: @JimmyKo I'd say it depends. If what you want is Dom events, like blur, click and key up for instance, than that's correct. But, if what you want are specific events for the ckeditor, than that would not be the case.

Comment: @DavidR Brilliant! The word **event** is too subtle to get attention. It is what I am looking for. I never think how close the answer I was. Can you post it to the answer? I would accept it :) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @n0m4d as well! Cheers.

Comment: @JimmyKo Posted!. Glad it helped you! :-)

Comment: Good job @DavidR! Thank you guys for the brainstorming =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the new UI of the CKEditor documentation website you can now find it [at this link](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#events)

Comment: It looks much better!

Comment: I've just changed the accepted answer because the link has been changed.

Answer (score 23):

For CKEditor4, Go to this [link](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor) and hover on the "Events" icon, you'll get all the events.

[image]

Hope this helps!