# Caputring events with ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have just brought CKEDITOR into a project and it imports fine and works. But Im not able to trap events. I tried the following:

```
var ckEditor = CKEDITOR.replace('notesInput');
CKEDITOR.instances.notesInput.on('input', function( ev ) 
{
                //Do whatever
});
```

notesInput is a textarea element. I want to fire off code whenever users type in the editor. Anyone know what im doing wrong?

Comment: I believe this has been answered a bunch of times on SO such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721916/how-to-listen-to-basic-events-in-ckeditor) - unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `input` event in CKEDITOR [[see list of events]](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor)

However, `change` or `focus` might be sufficient for what you're trying to accomplish:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('foo');
CKEDITOR.instances.foo.on('change', function(){
    console.log('bar baz bim');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wahwahwah/3jntv0h9/)